# mysql alter table FOREIGN KEY!

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

(I using workbench) i have table `questions` with `id, user_id, text` and  table `users` with fields `id, name`

I need to relate this 2 tables!

I write following:

```
ALTER TABLE `mydb_development`.`questions`
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_QueUsers_1
FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`)
REFERENCES `mydb_development`.`users`(`id`);
```

but i get:

```
ERROR 1046: No database selected
SQL Statement:
ALTER TABLE  `questions` 
ADD FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users`(`id`)

ERROR: Error when running failback script. Details follow.

ERROR 1046: No database selected
SQL Statement:
CREATE TABLE `questions` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `text` text NOT NULL,
  `security_token` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=373 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

ERROR 1046: No database selected
SQL Statement:
ALTER TABLE  `questions` 
ADD FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users`(`id`)

ERROR: Error when running failback script. Details follow.

.....................
```

**EDIT:**
I tried to do:

```
USE `mydb_development`;

ALTER TABLE  `mydb_development`.`questions`

ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_QueUsers_1`

FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`)

REFERENCES  `mydb_development`.`users`(`id`);
```

and i get error:

```
Error Code: 1005
Can't create table 'survey_development.#sql-4ad_45' (errno: 150)
```

DOnt understand:S

**EDIT:**

my user table:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb_development`.`users`;
CREATE TABLE  `mydb_development`.`users` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: post create for `survey_development`

Comment: try to create to tables again and add constraints add indexs

Comment: Please show us the create table for `users`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be mysql bug:

Read http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?22,19755,19755

Try to index the 'user_id' and run the script again.

Answer (score 0):

enter:

```
use `mydb_development`;
```

change the constraint name 'user_id' to something else like 'fk_user_id'

Comment: thanks for response, i edited , but nothing, i updated my post!

Answer (score 0):

Try selecting your database to see if it makes any difference

```
USE `mydb_development`;
```

Comment: thanks for response, i edited , but nothing, i updated my post!

Answer (score 0):

First of all you want to get rid of the `ERROR 1046: No database selected` errors.

To do this make sure that you either:

- Select a database with `USE mydb_development;`
- Modify the `ALTER/CREATE` statements to include the db. E.g. `ALTER TABLE  mydb_development.questions`

Comment: thanks for response, i edited , but nothing, i updated my post!

Comment: That looks like a different foreign key error. Have a look for other people's solutions to the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=foreign+key+150